# Select only if date in row has not passed yet

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting rows that have a 'Date' column. The date is formatted like so: 2022-01-08 14:00:00.

So today is: 2022-01-05 11:00, I wish to select every row that has a date beyond today's date.

Is there any way that I can select the rows where the date has not yet passed?

**EDIT:
Ergest Basha's comment was just what I was looking for:**

```
Date <= current_timestamp()
```

Comment: You mean null or black?

Comment: I just edited my question!

Comment: `Date <= current_timestamp()`

Comment: @ErgestBasha This was just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select * from table_name where date >= now()
```